# LINQ returns NULL

Tags: asp.net, linq, null

```
Item_SubContractor Item = (
    from Isc in db.Item_SubContractors
    where Isc.SubContract_id == tempSubContractId
    && Isc.Item_id == BOQItem.id
    select Isc).ToList().FirstOrDefault();
```

`Item` is returning NULL, when `db.Item_SubContractors`, `tempSubContractId`, `BOQItem.id` all return something when I break point and run through it

Someone has any ideas how can I solve this problem?

Thanks

Comment: check if the Database has the record you want to retrieve.

Comment: all return something, but how about the `&&` that you need to both parts be true ?

Comment: You clearly don't have a SubContractor who's `SubContract_id == tempSubContractId && Isc.Item_id == BOQItem.id`.

Comment: I think the problem has been pinpointed above, but as a side note `ToList()` before `FirstOrDefault()` is redundant and will decrease performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `FirstOrDefault()` will return `NULL` if you don't have the value in your Database then be sure that the same item exist in your database

you can  test this

```
bool exist = db.Item_SubContractors.Any(
                          Isc=> Isc.SubContract_id == tempSubContractId 
                          && Isc.Item_id == BOQItem.id)
```

to check if you have this item in your database